# Aplicación web con el modelo MVC ASP.NET me sale “El error del proveedor subyacente en open”. muchas gracias

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mvc

Esta es la cadena de conexión que tengo en visual studio 2019 RC

```
Public ActionResult Enter (string user, string password) 

{
   try 
   {
        using (cursomvcEntities1 db = new cursomvcEntities1 ()) 
        {
             var lst = from d in db.user 
                       where d.email == usuario && d.password == password && d. idState == 1 
                       select d; 
             if (lst.Count ()> 0) 
             {
                 user oUser = lst.First (); 
                 Session ["User"] = oUser; 
                 return Content ("1"); 
             } 
             else 
             {
                 return Content ("Usuario Inválido :(");
             }
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        return Content("Ocurrió un error :( "+ex.Message);
   }
}
```

1. Reinicié el servicio de Coordinador de Transacciones Distribuidas y no funcionó, me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Nota: Antes funcionaba muy normal con el usuario que tengo la base de datos en sql server, pero no sé que ha pasado ahora realmente.

Agradezco una pronta solución, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el ConectionString en el web.config, cuando te dice que esta ese error es por que no puede establecer la conexión a la base de datos ya sea por las credenciales o por que no puede llegar a la ip del server.

Revisa el conectionString con el nombre cursomvcEntities1.

Si estas con Sql server ingresa con el managment studio con los mismos datos del conectionString y válida si puedes llegar.